NetworkX: getting arrows/edges to point right
Is there a way to re-write my code at the end so that the graph it produces looks like this

Instead of like this

As a bonus, would anyone also know how to put in text labels above the nodes like in the 1st photo?
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

G = nx.DiGraph()
G.add_edges_from([(1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 4), (2, 5), (3, 6), (4, 7), (5, 7), (3, 8), (5, 8), (7, 9), (8, 9), (6, 10), (9, 10)])

pos = nx.spring_layout(G)
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos, node_size=500)
nx.draw_networkx_edges(G, pos, edgelist=G.edges())
nx.draw_networkx_labels(G, pos)

plt.show()


You can use the graphviz layout with the dot program to get pretty close:
pos=nx.drawing.nx_agraph.graphviz_layout(G, prog='dot', args='-Grankdir=LR')

This will result in the following plot:

If you want the rankings to match, it gets a little more complicated. Using this answer, you can do something like this:
A = nx.nx_agraph.to_agraph(G)
A.add_subgraph([2,3], rank='same')
A.add_subgraph([4,5], rank='same')
A.add_subgraph([7,8,6], rank='same')
with open('my_graph.png', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(A.draw(prog='dot', format='png', args='-Grankdir=LR'))

This results in:


The one at the top will do. The problem is, when I try using the line of code you gave me, I get the following error message: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pygraphviz'

You're right, I forgot to mention you need to install PyGraphviz: https://pygraphviz.github.io/documentation/stable/install.html

I'm a Windows user and I'm having some problems with getting PyGraphviz to work. Would you (or anyone else) know of any alternative solutions?

I managed to get it working BTW. I basically used conda install graphviz pygraphviz -c alubbock and included C:\Program Files\Graphviz\bin in the "path" system variable (see resources below)
https://github.com/pygraphviz/pygraphviz/issues/186#issuecomment-481760487
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ti2Br2Pq_A4
https://www.java.com/en/download/help/path.html
